# How to make a row in listview checked when the row is selected and vice versa in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox

I am having a listview and using view as gridview as follows:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,10,10" Name="listView2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="listView2_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Select">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox  />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Header="First Name" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}" Header="Last Name" Width="100"/>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>    
        </ListView>
```

Now the issue is that when the user will check on the checkbox the record should get selected. Also is the user selects the record from the list then the corresponding checkboxes should be selected.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest ways:

```
      <GridViewColumn Header="None">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Width="50"
                                      Height="50"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}},
                                                          Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}" />

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that your view model has IsSelected property:

```
    public Boolean IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (isSelected != value)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
    private Boolean isSelected;
```

So, let's change markup:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <!-- add style for the item in list view: -->
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">

            <GridViewColumn Header="Select">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- bind the checkbox to the IsSelected property: -->
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="100"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```